Why are the outcomes of this magnetic interaction different in different reference frames?
Suppose there's a long, positively charged beam oriented along the x-axis. Two test masses, each with the same positive charge, are placed at an equal distance from this beam. In one reference frame, the beam and test mass B are stationary, while test mass A is moving to the left:

Since the beam is stationary, there are no magnetic forces. Since the test masses have equal charge, the electric force is the same for both of them. If both test masses begin accelerating downward at the same rate, this tells us they must have the same mass. But if they have the same mass while mass A is moving, special relativity tells us that mass B must have a larger rest mass, by a factor of:
$$
m_{B}=m_{A}(1+v^{2}/2c^{2})
$$
(assuming v<<c)
If we switch to another reference frame, where mass A is stationary while the beam and mass B are moving to the right, the two masses should still have the same vertical acceleration:

But in this frame, mass B is moving and therefore should have a higher relativistic mass, by a factor of:
$$
m_{B}=m_{A}(1+v^{2}/c^{2})
$$
(again disregarding terms of higher order than 2)
In order for both masses to accelerate at the same rate, a greater repulsive force must be applied to mass B. Since they have the same charge, any discrepancy in force must be due to a magnetic force on mass B. However, since mass B is moving in the same direction as the beam, the magnetic force on it will be attractive, thus reducing the net repulsive force. This leads to the conclusion that mass B will accelerate slower than mass A in this reference frame, which is impossible. Where is the error in my reasoning?
I tried finding an answer to this online, and found that the ratio between the electric and magnetic forces for moving charges will go as (v/c)^2:
https://academic.mu.edu/phys/matthysd/web004/l0220.htm
Which is consistent with my calculation, but the force is still in the wrong direction.

You cannot use SR when there are accelerations.A accelerometer in a reference frame will always count 0 .

The reference frames aren't accelerating.

Object A and B feel a electrostatic force which means that they are accelerating.There are many errors in this question.Lets have the case of 2 events event1 and event2.In SR changing the frame of reference cannot change the fact that both event1 and event2 will happen,but only the order.For some observers event1 happens before event2 and for others event2 happens before event1 and for others event1 and event2 may happen at the same time.Regardless of change of reference frame ,the laws of physics remain the same and therefore both events must happen.

@RootGroves It is completely false that SR cannot handle accelerations.

These test masses can be arbitrarily close together, so all observers should agree on the order in which they e.g. reach fixed vertical coordinates.

In both frames the forces are the same.
In both frames the mass-energies are different.
So therefore in both frames the accelerations are different.
In both frames the acceleration of the charge that is moving in that frame is lower.
Let's replace the moving charge by a moving rocket with some finite amount of fuel. The moving rocket burns fuel slowly (time dilation of the change of amount of fuel).
This increases the time to reach the final speed. And also the final speed is lower (time dilation of change of position).
So the acceleration is reduced by gamma squared. In the rocket case. Not in the charge case, where it's reduced by gamma.
By the way, the moving charge decelerates horizontally when it accelerates vertically.
And the moving rocket decelerates horizontally when it accelerates vertically, if the direction of the thrust is suitable.
